# A function that takes a list and returns the same list but without the duplicates

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So as the title says I'm supposed to make a function that takes a list and returns the list without the duplicates, but I can't use list comprehensions, only high-order functions and lambdas.

I've found this code from another users question.

```
has :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Bool
has [] _ = False
has (x:xs) a
  | x == a    = True
  | otherwise = has xs a

unique :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
unique [] = []
unique (x:xs)
  | has xs x  = unique xs
  | otherwise = x : unique xs
```

I understand how it works, but I don't understand how I could do the same thing with high-order fuctions. I'm new to Haskell so any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: The good news is: you don't use list comprehensions.

Comment: Do you know what a higher-order function *is*? For example, `any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` would be useful in implementing `has`: `has xs a = any (== a) xs`.

Comment: This is kinda hard, but I would suggest to use `foldr`. Try implementing `has`, `id`, `filter` and `map` using `foldr`, then try to find the pattern and do the same with `unique`. Hint: you may need to change how it works, and instead use `unique (x:xs) = let res = unique xs in if has res x then res else x:res`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I can't use list comprehensions, only high-order functions and lambdas.

The good news is: you don't use list comprehensions.

You can work with [**`foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) here. Here the first function takes an element of type `a` and the "result" of the function of the rest of the list (so here the unique list of elements of the remaining elements). Your function thus should check if the element already appears in that result. You thus can implement this with:

```
unique :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
unique = foldr f []
    where f x xs
            | … = …
            | otherwise = …
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` parts. You can even  generalize this to any `Foldable`:

```
unique :: (Eq a, Foldable f) => f a -> [a]
unique = foldr f []
    where f x xs
            | … = …
            | otherwise = …
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I can't use foldr because we haven't learned it in the course yet.

Comment: @YaBoi: you need to learn a higher-order function before you can use it?

Comment: Yeah we were specificaly told not to use it because it will be covered next week.

Comment: @YaBoi Then please be more specific than "*I can't use list comprehensions, only high-order functions and lambdas*" - what functions *can* you use?

Comment: @Bergi It turns out I misunderstood the assignment, sorry for wasting your guys' time.

Answer (score 2):

You have been suggested `foldr` in another answer. This works for your `has` function but not for `unique`. The refactoring to foldr can be systematised, as taught in Graham Hutton's paper *"A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold"*.

In essence `g = fold f v` if and only if it can be written in the form,

```
g [ ] = v
g (x : xs) = f x (g xs)
```

Let's see how this works for the function `has`.  **Note:** I will flip the order of the arguments in `has` to make it simpler.

```
has :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
has _ [] = False
has a (x:xs)
  | x == a    = True
  | otherwise = has a xs
```

We need to figure out our `g`, `v` and `f`.

**`g`** - The function `has` isn't quite our function `g` since it the latter only takes a list as argument and `has` also takes an `a`. Rather `g = has a`.

**`v`** - That one is trivial, `v = False`

**`f`** - According to the above it should satisfy `f x (g xs) = g (x : xs)`, that is,

```
f x (has a xs) 
  | x == a    = True
  | otherwise = has a xs
```

here we generalise the argument `has a xs` to any `y`, resulting in

```
f x ys = 
  | x == a    = True
  | otherwise = ys
```

or in its lambda form if you prefer,

```
f = \x ys ->
  | x == a    = True
  | otherwise = ys
```

arriving at,

```
has a = foldr f False 
  where 
    f x ys =
      | x == a    = True
      | otherwise = ys
```

Now let's see why it does not work for `unique`.

```
unique :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
unique [] = []
unique (x:xs)
  | has x xs  = unique xs
  | otherwise = x : unique xs
```

Again we need to figure out our `g`, `v` and `f`. The `g` is of course our `unique` function. The `v = []`, the base case. Finally from second equation for `g` it follows that `f` should satisfy `f x (g xs) = g (x : xs)`.

```
f x (unique xs) = 
  | has x xs  = unique xs
  | otherwise = x : unique xs
```

again lets abstract over `unique xs` to get a definition for `f`,

```
f x ys = 
  | has x xs  = ys
  | otherwise = x : ys
```

That did not work out because of the `xs` that remains in the definition. Note that the property `g (x : xs) = f x (g xs)` is specifying that the recursion is performed by applying a lambda at each step that only acts on `x` and the result of `g xs`. It does not act on xs.

We can change the definition of `unique` to make it a foldr though. Your definition checks if `x` is in `xs`, i.e. in the unprocessed list of elements, and if it is it doesn't add it. We can do the opposite, and check for `x` in the processed list of elements to check if it has already been added.

```
unique2 :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
unique2 [] = []
unique2 (x:xs)
  | has x zs  = zs
  | otherwise = x : zs
  where zs = unique2 xs
```

with this change we have that `f` should satisfy,

```
f x (unique2 xs) = 
  | has x zs  = zs
  | otherwise = x : zs
  where zs = unique2 xs
```

and abstracting over `unique2 xs`, we get,

```
f x ys = 
  | has x ys  = ys
  | otherwise = x : ys
```

thus,

```
unique2 = foldr f []
  where 
    f x ys =
    | has x ys  = ys
    | otherwise = x : ys
```